# Counterparts of Anglophile

Tags: single-word-requests

In English class, when discussing the symbiotic relationship between the United Kingdom and the United States—particularly in regards to the institutions of the two—my teacher used the word *Anglophile*. I looked it up in the Merriam-Webster dictionary, and I really liked it: I found it very practical and applicable.

Its formation is pretty straightforward: *Anglo-* + *-phile*, where *Anglo-* is the Late Latin prefix that means "English" and *-phile* indicates love, fondness, etc.

My question is: are there any equivalents of this word that refer to a love or lover of other ethnicities or nationalities, such as of the US? If not, is there a concise hyphenated word one could use?

Comment: Francophile, Sinophile, etc. Your question reads too broad and what does your research show?

Comment: I think you can edit your question focusing on the US.

Comment: Beware .. You are among linguophiles ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst ***Francophile*** is well-known and much used (like Anglophile), it is difficult to think of others that are in daily currency.

However, both Merriam Webster and the OED have entries for ***Americanophile***.

The OED's meaning and examples are listed hereunder.

> A person who loves or admires the United States or its culture.
>
> 1894   N.-Y. Times 26 Feb. 3/2   He was transformed from a bibliophile
>   into an Americanophile.
>
> 1939   Sunday Times-Signal (Zanesville, Ohio)  17 Sept. i. 4/6   The
>   Association..is composed of French Americanophiles and American
>   Francophiles.
>
> 1972   C. Barnett Collapse Brit. Power v. 346   A sentimental
>   Americanophile whose pro-American sentiments were shared by his
>   colleagues.
>
> 2000   Publishers Weekly 4 Sept. 54/2   An Americanophile who has put
>   America into more than one of his own novels.
>
> B. adj.
>
> Characterized by love of or admiration for the United States or its
>   culture.
>
> 1919   N.Y. Times 12 Oct. 6/1   The..British view of our country and
>   our people..[is] undoubtedly Americanophile.
>
> 1942   Dunkirk (N.Y.) Evening Observer 12 Oct. 16/4   The president of
>   Chile, whose sincere Americanophile disposition..[is] the same as his
>   government's.
>
> 1979   Rev. Politics 41 495   The existence of well-defined
>   Americanophile groups is not often immediately evident.
>
> 2003   Maclean's (Electronic ed.) 21 Apr. 4   This is when Canada's
>   national magazine should defend Canada and not be Americanophile
>   sycophants.

Comment: Sinophile and Russophile (and variant forms e.g. sinophilic, Russophil) are in Merriam-Webster, but they seem the most common of the others.

Comment: @Stuart F Turkmenistanophile would take a bit of getting your tongue around wouldn't it!